Referencing Formula in another cell, not Value
Does anyone know how I could do this:
Cell C4 in "Template Table" has a formula.
I want cell C10 in "Copy Table" to reference the formula in C4, not its value.
When I change the formula in C4, I want the formula in C10 to be the same as C4.


Don't you just mean to copy paste (formula)? Else can you give an example of your problem?

Use the Name Manager in Excel - Microsoft Support you may want to consider named range/formulas also.

@nkalvi make that into an answer and I'll upvote it.

FMI: In what case should it needed? Why copy/paste is not good?

I will be copying the template and pasting it 200+ times. If a formula breaks or needs updating, I don't want to copy and paste the formula again that many times, I want them all to update automatically based on the template

You could use name manager to define this as a named formula and use it anywhere in the worksheet. For example,

with C4 being the active cell, select Formulas > Name Manager > New

enter new_hire for the name

enter your formula as 'refers to':
IF(B4="New Hire Employee", "This is a New Hire Employee","This is a Post-Probationary Employee")

this creates a named formula with IF(left cell="New Hire...

then you can enter =new_hire anywhere in the workbook where mapping is needed

when you want to make a change, update the formula in Name Manager and all references will be updated automatically

I have not added any error checking to keep the example simple




You're most welcome @Jean!

You can do it with VBA:
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Check if the cell C4 in the "Template Table" is modified
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Copy the formula from C4 to C10
        Sh.Range("C10").Formula = Sh.Range("C4").Formula
    End If
End Sub

